# Intuition behind the Canonical Hamiltonian Ensemble

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

I read about the canonical Hamiltonian ensemble interpretation [here](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-021-89400-3).

Say we consider quantum state which with probability $p_\lambda$ evolves under a Hamiltonian $\hat{H}_\lambda$ part of an ensemble of Hamiltonians. For example, the Hamiltonian might have a stochastic term. Say that initially this quantum state is a pure state given by $\rho(0)$. Then, it may evolve into some state $\rho_\lambda(t)$. The canonical Hamiltonian ensemble says that the Hamiltonian-ensemble-averaged evolution is given by
$$
\overline{\rho}(t)=\int p_\lambda \hat{U}_\lambda\rho(0)\hat{U}_\lambda^\dagger d\lambda
$$
assuming $\lambda$ is a continuous parameter. Here $\hat{U}_\lambda$ is the unitary evolution corresponding to $\hat{H}_\lambda$. Then, any observable we expect from this system is given by the expectation value calculated with respect to this average state $\overline{\rho}(t)$, i.e. $$\overline{\left\langle\hat{O}\right\rangle}=\mathrm{Tr}\left\{\overline{\rho}\hat{O}\right\}$$

It seems that we have two layers of statistics here and it is evident that $\overline{\rho}$ is able to lose its purity, being a mixed state. **I would like to know the intuition behind this interpretation**.

At the time of writing, I am fixated on treating the Hamiltonian ensemble as something physical, i.e. I imagine there being a large number of identical systems forming an ensemble, all having the intiial state $\rho(0)$. For example, we may have identical, noninteracting spins in a solid, all in their ground state. A fraction $p_\lambda$ of this physical ensemble evolves under the Hamiltonian $\hat{H}_\lambda$ into the state $\rho_\lambda(t)$. We can then take the expectation value for each system with respect to their state, $$\left\langle\hat{O}\right\rangle_\lambda=\mathrm{Tr}\left\{\rho_\lambda\hat{O}\right\}$$ The Hamiltonian-ensemble-averaged expectation value is then found by averaging over all the systems forming the ensemble,
$$
\overline{\left\langle\hat{O}\right\rangle} = \int p_\lambda\left\langle\hat{O}\right\rangle_\lambda d\lambda
$$
(Of course it is counterintuitive to do an integral here, a sum would be more appropriate but it should be justified by the ensemble being large). In this way of viewing things, I deliberately average over the statistical ensemble corresponding to the expectation value of the observable first, then average over the Hamiltonian ensemble. However, I am not sure whether this intuition fits the description. **Does it make the same interpretation? Or something different altogether?**